# Sum() returning a copy of the last column in df?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to pandas and seem to get a repeated column rather than the sum of two.[CSV](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qymx853chq6e88w/0xb4a0a46d3042a739ec76fd67a3f1b99cc12ac1d9_mcap.csv?dl=0)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut6bG.png)

```
df = pd.read_csv('0xb4a0a46d3042a739ec76fd67a3f1b99cc12ac1d9_mcap.csv', sep=',')

df1 = df.copy(deep=True)

df2 = df1.loc[:, ('mcap_token0', 'mcap_token1')]

df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

df2.loc[:, 'sum'] = df2.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Instead of `df1.loc[:, ('mcap_token0', 'mcap_token1')]`, just use `df1[('mcap_token0', 'mcap_token1')]`, and instead of `df2.loc[:, 'sum']` simply write `df['sum']` ;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code is not reproducible. We don't know what your `df` looks like. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. Don't paste code or data as images.

Comment: @richardec: actually, the OP's use of `df1.loc[:, ('mcap_token0', 'mcap_token1')]` may or may not indicate a `MultiIndex` column. In the case of `MultiIndex`, it does translate to `df1[('mcap_token0', 'mcap_token1')]`. Otherwise, it would have to be `df1[['mcap_token0', 'mcap_token1']]`.

Comment: I'm guessing this is happening because the numbers are too large.

Comment: How do you solve the issue of large numbers? @richardec

Comment: Do *not* post links to data, and do not use *images*. Data and code should be part of the question itself as *text*

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine, just you don't see it behind the decimals
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you accept this as answer for me? I kinda need the 50 reputation to ask some questions, thankyou!

Comment: **Do not post images of code**